# Alternative to using multiple flags to show hide multiple elements

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm using multiple flags to show/hide certain elements in my angular component. For example, if 'Add New' is clicked, I set addNewClicked to true. If 'Update' clicked, I set updateClicked flag to true. And based on the flags, I show/hide multiple elements. When this flag is true, show 'A' & 'B' element, When another flag true, hide 'A' and show 'B' & 'C' and so on..
As I keep adding new operations, number of flags is growing, I have created almost 10-15 flags, which is becoming hard to manage. Is there any alternative to using multiple flags. How to better manage show/hide multiple elements based on different operations (button clicked or events).

Comment: It's very hard to answer this without seeing your code and all of the flag permutations.

Comment: Can you add your sample code with conditions?

Answer (score 0):

There are a "tecnique" that is using binary operator. I try explain with an example

Imagine you has an array like - I put in comments the value of index in binary-

```
data: any[] = [
  {name:"data1",index:1},           //[00001]
  {name:"data2",index:2},           //[00010]
  {name:"data3",index:4},           //[00100]
  {name:"data4",index:8},           //[01000]
  {name:"data5",index:16},          //[10000]
  {name:"data1 or data 2",index:3}, //[00011]
  {name:"data1 or data 3",index:5}, //[00101]
  {name:"data3 or data 4",index:12},//[01100]
  ]
```

And a function

```
show(index,count) {
    return index & Math.pow(2,count)
    //or, if we can that count=0 no show anything 
    //const binary=[0,1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128]
    //return index & binary[count]
}
```

If we has an html like

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of data">
  <div *ngIf="show(item.index,count)">{{item.name}}</div>
</ng-container>
<button (click)="count=count+1">click</button>
```

You see that, e.g. if count=2, Math.pow(2,2)=4 [00100], and show the data with index 4 [00100], 5 [00101], and 12 [01100] -all of them that the index in binary has an 1 in the 3rd position from last-

a simple [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fgpwsc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**Update** well, in general it's a bad idea using a function in an *ngFor, so we can has a function that add a propertie "visible" like

```
setModelVisible(count)
{
 this.data.forEach(x=>{
   x.visible=this.show(x.index,count)
 })
}
```

call to the funciton when change "count", and use data.visible in the *ngIf